# pytest/mixer Django - fixture ignores field value when it's inherited from another model

Tags: pytest, pytest-django, django-mixer

All my models, including `Report` inherit from `BaseModel`:

```
class Report(BaseModel):
      ...

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I'm trying to test a scheduled tasks that deletes old `Report` objects.

Below is a fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def old_dummy_report(request, db):
    ### set the date to far back
    old_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=900)
    return mixer.blend("core.report", , created_date=old_date, ios_report={'1': 1}, android_report={'1': 1})
```

However, when I run the test and inspect the `created_date` field for `old_dummy_report`, I always get the date at the time the test is run.

How can I rectify this, besides re-setting the date to `old_date` in the test function itself (which seems unpythonic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I guess this has to do with the `auto_now_add=True` parameter.

I've changed the pytest fixture function to this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def old_dummy_report(request, db):
    old_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=900)
    obj = mixer.blend("core.report", ios_report={'1': 1}, android_report={'1': 3}, created_date=old_date)
    obj.created_date = old_date
    obj.save()
    return obj
```

So, first create the object and let Django `auto_now_add`, then change the `created_date` manually.